# SNR of input signal of A/D converter

Tags: signals, adc

Hello i find this question. i am trying to solve it

My question is

**12 bit ADC has input signal range of +-1V . the signal to quantization ratio if a sine wave signal with 0.25V peak voltage is given as input**

I know that equation of SNR is 1.8+6n.

so I solved it.

For 12 bit ADC SNR must be 73.8 dB.

but solution is 62 dB.

so my answer is wrong. can you tell me why my answer is wrong??

**Does peak voltage changes SNR??**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer from this link

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66261/signal-to-noise-ratio-problem

SNR = 10Log((Vcc^2)/(Vpp^2))+1.8+6n

so answer will be 62 dB